# Rewrite Rule for id .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is there any possibility to rewrite url's with get variables globally, instead of specific files?

Changing

```
http://example.com/{something}?id=1
```

To:

```
http://example.com/{something}/id/1
```

Or without the word id:

```
http://example.com/{something}/1
```

This is what I got so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.phtml
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.phtml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
```

With this I could remove the .phtml extension

I hope there is a specific answer for this!

Comment: Ask the right question: Is it possible to use a matched part of the pattern in the substitution? The answer is yes, and the documentation explains how.

Comment: @CBroe I do not understand the question and neither the answer. Where is this documentation you're talking about?

Comment: How come you have not _started_ by checking the documentation for the technology you want to use? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know there is a documentation for htaccess. Seems like it's a big thing

Comment: Altough I could not make out of the documentation how this works. You can call me stupid but I just don't understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming something to be a php file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/id/([\d]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L] #with id in between
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\d]+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [L] #without id in between
```

You have to make sure rules are not conflicting.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works like a charm. Marking as the right answer.

Comment: Is this possible with numbers only?

Comment: So I can't just remove the \d and it will work with words too?

Comment: for words use `\w`.

Comment: Now I found out 1 problem: http://example.com/login/id/1 works. But http://example.com/login gets a 404 not found

Comment: You have to manage your rules arrange and debug them part by part.